# OPENCV Detection of close objects

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I'm learning opencv and I have a question for you. I got this final processed image.
[image: objects detection]

The original image is two balls that are near and they are the same color. I would get the center and the radius of each ball. If the balls are distant I do this using findContours and drawContours with option CV_FILLED, so I can do the average of the pixel position of each ball and I get the center. The problem is when the balls are close so I don't get two different contours and I can't do the average of the pixel position. I obtain this image (the center is indicated with a circle): 
[image]

Could you give some advice?
I do the edge detection using Canny algorithm.

Comment: do you want to get ONE center as you showed in your second image, or TWO centers for each circle?

Comment: I want to get two centers for each circle.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple matlab code to detect two circles:

```
filen='https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDNS8.jpg'  % your image
I=imread(filen);

I=im2bw(I(:,:,3)); % gray scale

Rmin=20;Rmax=70;  % circle range

% find circles in the image with Hough transform
[centersDark, radiiDark] = imfindcircles(I, [Rmin Rmax], ...
                                        'ObjectPolarity','dark','sensitivity',0.93)
                                    imagesc(I),hold on
 viscircles(centersDark, radiiDark,'LineStyle','--');hold off
```

Result:
[image]

As @ChronoTrigger mentioned above, hough transform package in opencv should work for your case.

Comment: I've tried to use hough package in opencv, I read the documentation of this function HoughCircles at http://http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghcircles 
but I really don't understand this parameters: dp, param1, param2. I wrote this: 
    HoughCircles(color_dst, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.1, 5, 100, 30, 10, 100 ); 
This configuration seems to be the best (but I detect 3 circles instead of 2), could you give me a simple explanation of this parameters to improve the detection? 

PS: I pass the first image I've posted to the function.

Comment: try adjusting your param2 (30 in your HoughCircles), that is accumulator threshold. I guess the smaller it is set, the more circles are detected.

Comment: I've created two trackbars for "param2" and "dp" but according to the position of the balls the perfect paramaters are quite different. If I would create an alghoritm that detect all the balls in the picture (radius and center) with the above parameters setted, what should I do? For example, are there other functions/alghoritms that can help me?

Comment: I would suggest you only change the "param2", "dp" is a prior estimation and once set, do not change it. Have you already correctly detected two circles with the radius&position?

Comment: Yes, I have. Oh, ok I'll do that. How can I choose the "dp" parameter? The best values seems to be 1 and 1.1. I really don't understand this parameter.

Comment: dp is inverse ratio of the accumulator resolution to the image resolution. You can set it to a constant, for example, 1, and only adjust the accumulator param2.

Answer (score 1):

A Hough transformation is a common approach to detect geometrical entities in the image. OpenCV has a function implemented for circles. Check this out:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html

Comment: Oh I didn't know this possibility, I'll check this option.

Comment: I've tried to use hough package in opencv, I read the documentation of this function HoughCircles at http://http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghcircles 
but I really don't understand this parameters: dp, param1, param2. I wrote this: 
    HoughCircles(color_dst, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.1, 5, 100, 30, 10, 100 ); 
This configuration seems to be the best (but I detect 3 circles instead of 2), could you give me a simple explanation of this parameters to improve the detection? 

PS: I pass the first image I've posted to the function.